# How to find the data in mysql with per word?

Tags: mysql

So if I use this code `SELECT * FROM user where BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%{$search}%')` If I search for words **LEE**, Then, all the letters that uses LEE will appear. 
LIke S**LEE**P, **LEE** YONE, U**LEE**, **LEE**OPARD etc. 
And worse still, if I search for the letter "A" everything will appear.

Can make only per word? maybe if I search for words **LEE**, that will appear only **LEE** YONE

Comment: SELECT * FROM user where BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('{$search} %') OR BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('% {$search}') OR BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('% {$search} %') OR BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('{$search}')

Comment: why exactly do you explicitely use a `binary` comparison and then cast *both* your keyword **and your data** to lowercase to get a case-insensitive (=non-binary) comparison, while completely **voiding all potential index benefits** and predictably *killing* your performance in large tables?

Comment: you should add single space in start & end of your $search variable, like this: ` $search = " " . $search . " ";` and then use this variable in query. 
OR you can add spaces in query as well like this: `SELECT * FROM user where BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('% {$search} %')`
This is because space is the thing that separate words in string.

Comment: @RavendraPatel and what about a value like "this is a sentence with LEE."? (note the trailing dot) - or just a plain "LEE"

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I accept your condition. So in this case can we not use like this: `%[^.? ]{$search}[^.? ]%`  ?
I have used dot, question mark and space in regular expression. mores characters can be added.

Comment: "A" would only return LEEOPARD

Answer (score 0):

Try `WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]LEE[[:>:]]'`

Also you **don't** need to `LOWER()` if your collation is set to a reasonable value.

Answer (score 0):

Your query `SELECT * FROM user where BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%{$search}%')` returns U**LEE** when your $search is **LEE** because of the wildcards (**%** signs) around your search term.

If you change it to `SELECT * FROM user where BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('{$search}')` your $search for **LEE** will only return entries that are *exactly* **LEE**.

If you also want **LEE** Yone returned, you need to change your query to   `SELECT * FROM user where BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('{$search}%')` (note the % after the search term).

Comment: which will also return "LEEOPARD"; which OP explicitely didn't want...

Answer (score 0):

Hi For this you have to use fulltext search

live excample check below link.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/159f95/15

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below query;

```
SELECT * FROM user where BINARY LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('% {$search} %') OR LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('{$search} %') OR LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('% {$search}')
```